# how to pass listView.builder index to a parameter of custom widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create a custom widget which will take listview.builder and return a list of items but I am not able to pass the index to paramater of custom widget when I am accessing it in another dart file it **throws 'index' not defined**.

this is my listView.builder and i am tyring to pass  `products[index]['name']` to `ProductContainer(products[index]['name'])` like this... but it throws index not defined error plz help

```html
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
      class ProductContainer extends StatefulWidget {
      final String image;
      final String name;
      final String price;
      final String tag;
      final Text text;
      final double height;
      final double width;

      ProductContainer({
        Key key,
        this.image,
        this.name,
        this.price,
        this.tag,
        this.text,
        this.height,
        this.width,
      }) : super(key: key);
      @override
      _ProductContainerState createState() => _ProductContainerState();
    }

    class _ProductContainerState extends State<ProductContainer> {
      var products = [
        {
          "price": " 100",
          "imageLink": "images/fs.jpg",
          "tag": "one",
          "name": "prod1",
          "category": "combo",
        }];
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return SizedBox(
              height: 150,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: products.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      forProducts(
                          height: 120,
                          width: 120,
                          image: image ?? image[index]['imageLink'],
                          tag: products[index]['tag'],
                          name: products[index]['name'],
                          category: products[index]["category"],
                          price: products[index]["price"],
                          context: context),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          }
        }

         Widget forProducts(
            {String image = "images/",
            @required String tag,
            @required String name,
            @required String category,
            @required String price,
            @required double height,
            @required double width,
            @required BuildContext context}) {
           return Column(children: [
           Material(
           child: Hero(
            tag: tag,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => InfoPage(
                              image: image,
                              tag: tag,
                              name: name,
                              category: category,
                              price: price,
                            )));
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                height: 120,
                width: 120,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover, image: AssetImage(image)),
                ),
              ),
            ))),
    Expanded(child: Text(name)),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with code.
`var products = [` doesn't have ending `]`

Comment: Can you check now I have corrected the syntax error it was caused because while pasting code here

Comment: The code for this widget seems fine. You should post the code for the other widget as well. The forProducts one.

Comment: Now I have added the widget forProducts You can check and I just resolved my issue Posting the answer now thnks for your interest @AbdurRafaySaleem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me, the mistake I did was I had not defined my List products in the dart file wherever I was using this ProductContainer Widget and also it wont take index unless passed as proper instance member with it so it should be like `widget.products[index]` and not like `products[index]` as products isnt defined in wherever you will be using your widget. Below is the proper working code.

```html
import 'package:my_Ecomm/screens/info_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final List products;
  final double height;
  final double width;
//final dynamic index; // you can use it like this also to pass index 
  const ProductContainer({
    Key key,
    this.products,
    this.height,
    //this.index,
    this.width,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ProductContainerState createState() => _ProductContainerState();
}

class _ProductContainerState extends State<ProductContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
    
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: widget.height + 45,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: widget.products.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return forProducts(
                  height: widget.height,
                  width: widget.width,
                  image: widget.products[index]['imageLink'],
                  tag: widget.products[index]['tag'],
                  name: widget.products[index]['name'],
                  category: widget.products[index]["category"],
                  price: widget.products[index]["price"],
                  context: context);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Widget forProducts(
    {String image = "images/",
    @required String tag,
    @required String name,
    @required String category,
    @required String price,
    @required double height,
    @required double width,
    @required BuildContext context}) {
  return Column(children: [
    Material(
        child: Hero(
            tag: tag,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => InfoPage(
                              image: image,
                              tag: tag,
                              name: name,
                              category: category,
                              price: price,
                            )));
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                height: height,
                width: width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover, image: AssetImage(image)),
                ),
              ),
            ))),
    Expanded(child: Text(name)),
  ]);
}
```